# Parametrization of a surface of revolution.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I am trying to construct a parametrization of a surface of revolution. By parametrization, I mean a patch for the surface that covers the entire surface. I am having trouble with even starting to find a parametrization. My question is how does one go about constructing a parametrization for a surface? For example:

(i) The surface of revolution of $y=cosh x$ around the x axis is a catenoid.

(ii) The surface of revolution of the circle $(x-2)^2+y^2=1$ around the y axis is a torus.

I'd like to do these myself so I request some guidance. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You know $y =coshx = \dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

So the parameterization would be $x = t$ and $y = \dfrac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$

I think

For the next one it is straight forward

$x = 2+cost$ and $y = sint$

Comment: I think there should be a + in place of - for the first one. I am looking to find a parametrization when these curves are revolved around a certain axis.

Comment: You are right about +.  My thought was you needed parameterization of the surface of revolution to simplify the process of either findind the volume or any metric.  You don't parameterize the surface of revolution around the axis of revolution. I think. I may be wrong.

Comment: This document may indeed give you the answers you are looking for http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/Fok/rudiments_surface_geometry.html#Ex2.9

Comment: Thanks. It seems helpful. Also, I think for the parametric equations of the circle, x should be 2+cos t and y be sin t. But I could be wrong. Thanks for the help though.